# Can't refresh materialized view with ormlite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have updated ServiceStack to latest version on a project and now this line seems to be giving me issues:

```
_db.ExecuteNonQuery("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW product_book;");
```

It generates this error in logs:

```
2020-08-25 23:14:26.8896||DEBUG|OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions|SQL: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW product_book; |url: |action: 
2020-08-25 23:17:19.6129||ERROR|ImportBookHelper|Error reading xml Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "product_book" does not exist
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 973
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 449
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 298
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1178
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 977
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 959
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ExecNonQuery(IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql, Object anonType) in C:\BuildAgent\work\27e4cc16641be8c0\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.cs:line 32
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter) in C:\BuildAgent\work\27e4cc16641be8c0\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteExecFilter.cs:line 64
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42P01
    MessageText: relation "product_book" does not exist
    File: namespace.c
    Line: 407
    Routine: RangeVarGetRelidExtended|url: |action:
```

I have tried running `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW product_book;` in the postgresql console and it runs fine.  I have also tried using `ExecuteSql()` but always the same issue.

It says relation doesn't exist but it does.  Also the connection string is definitely to the right database and it can read/write fine.

This used to work but now it seems to have stopped working and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to be an issue with OrmLite which just sends the SQL as-is to Npgsql ADO.NET provider which is returning the server PostgreSQL error.

For some reason the connection string doesn't have visibility or access to your `product_book` materialized view, some potential issues could be the user may not have access to it, or it's in a different schema.

Comment: @Guerrilla try using vanilla ADO.NET, you’ll likely end up with the same result